# Downloading as .txt including header,internal table footer with specific path

Tags: download, abap, internal-tables

i have a specifix path like C://asd , an internal table itab, and a footer and header.
I tried to use GUI_DOWNLOAD but, i can only send an internal table to this function.

I need to download these things .txt like this format

```
**  The account 21324.2342                 (Header)
    123 1231 123 1234 123 1234 123 1234    (itab[1])
    321 4321 321 4321 321 4321 321 4321    (itab[2])
    123 1231 123 1234 123 1234 123 1234    (itab[3])
    321 4321 321 4321 321 4321 321 4321    (itab[4])
    123 1231 123 1234 123 1234 123 1234    (itab[5])
    321 4321 321 4321 321 4321 321 4321    (itab[6])
    Sum is 123412                          (Footer)**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I usually do is create an internal table with 1 field of say 300 characters.

Then I write out each line into one entry of the internal table.

( Using WRITE and CONCATENATE )

Save the table and done!

PS : Also, that function module should be obsolete by now, I am fairly certain the OO version can store an internal table of strings, which is a more future-proof approach.